# How can i use same private variable in 2 functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So im having 2 functions. Problem is in `styep_id` variable. I know that i can just declare it in second functions, but then he wont take out data from first function. So the question is `how i can use the same variable without lost data on him`

*P.S* It shouldn't be public variable, cos it wont work. It wont hold the data.

```
    function delete_estimate_position_type() {
        var estpt_tr_jqobj, estpt_action_links_td_jqobj, styep_id, authenticity_token, request_url, stya_id;

        styep_id = $(this).attr("styep_id");

        // Ja ir tikko kā pievienots, tad tikai izmetīsim ārā no DOM
        if (!styep_id == "") {
            estpt_action_links_td_jqobj = $(this).parent();
            estpt_tr_jqobj = estpt_action_links_td_jqobj.parent();
            stya_id = $("td.service-type-est-position-estimate-position-type-name>input.stya-id-for-styep", estpt_tr_jqobj).val();
            estpt_tr_jqobj.remove();
            show_stya_delete_link_if_possible(stya_id);
            remove_estpgt_if_has_no_estpt($(this).attr("estpgt_id"));
        }
}
```

And

```
function save_configuration(){
  var estpt_for_estpgt = "";
  // Pārbaudam vai visām tāmes pozīciju grupām ir norādītas tāmes pozīcijas
  $('.estpt-for-estpgt').each(function(){
    if ($(this).find('tr.action_record_tr').size() == 0){
      estpt_for_estpgt = this;
      return false;
    }
  })

  if (estpt_for_estpgt == "") {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.submit();
            // Dzēsīsim ārā no datu bāzes
            authenticity_token = $("#authenticity_token").val();
            request_url = "/service_type_est_positions/" + styep_id + "/destroy_from_service_type_config";

            $.post(request_url, { authenticity_token: authenticity_token}, process_service_type_est_position_delete, "json");
  } else {
    $.alerts.okButton = 'Labi';
    jError("Vismaz vienai Tāmes pozīciju grupai nav norādīta neviena Tāmes pozīcija!", "Kļūda");
  }

  return false;
}

function remove_estpgt_if_has_no_estpt(estpgt_id) {
    // Paskatīsimies vai eksistē kāda tāmes pozīcija
    if ($("#estpt_for_" + estpgt_id + ">tr:first").size() == 0) {
        $("#estpgt_" + estpgt_id).remove();
        $("#estpt_tr_for_" + estpgt_id).remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass it in function calling. or another way is you can set value in hidden field when first function is call and in section function call you can get value from hidden field.

Comment: Why not using a closure properly and defining your functions and your variable in the scope of this closure? Of course, if you can choose where to define your functions... Else, you have no other proper way than to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call your second function within the first and pass the variable as an argument:

```
function delete_estimate_position_type() { 
   save_configuration(styep_id)
}

function save_configuration(id){
   request_url = "/service_type_est_positions/" + id + "/destroy_from_service_type_config";
}
```

Comment: Only 1 problem. `save_configuration` function should be used only by pressing button "save", but now its "duplicated" and used also by `delete_estimate_position_type` function button

Comment: Used global scope variable to check if the function was executed, but then on save i'm receiving this error - http://prntscr.com/jkiemg

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 function delete_estimate_position_type() {
        var estpt_tr_jqobj, estpt_action_links_td_jqobj, styep_id, authenticity_token, request_url, stya_id;

        styep_id = $(this).attr("styep_id");

       // your other code goes here.....
       // Your variable pass as argument
            remove_estpgt_if_has_no_estpt($(this).attr("estpgt_id"),styep_id.val() );
        }
}
```

// Get it from argument.

```
function remove_estpgt_if_has_no_estpt(estpgt_id,styep_id ) {
    // Paskatīsimies vai eksistē kāda tāmes pozīcija
    if ($("#estpt_for_" + estpgt_id + ">tr:first").size() == 0) {
        $("#estpgt_" + estpgt_id).remove();
        $("#estpt_tr_for_" + estpgt_id).remove();
    }
}
```

Another option is set it in hidden field.

// html

```
<input type = "hidden" id="styep_id_newval" value="">
```

// End of html

```
function delete_estimate_position_type() {
        var estpt_tr_jqobj, estpt_action_links_td_jqobj, styep_id, authenticity_token, request_url, stya_id;

        styep_id = $(this).attr("styep_id");

       // your other code goes here.....
       $("#styep_id_newval").(styep_id.val());

       // Your variable pass as argument
            remove_estpgt_if_has_no_estpt($(this).attr("estpgt_id"),styep_id.val() );
        }
}
```

Now you can easily access code using anywhere.

```
$("styep_id_newval").val();
```

Comment: If im doing how u said - im getting this type of error - http://prntscr.com/jkiemg But i cant use second method, cos the web-service is on Ruby and its not made by me, so there is another structure.

Comment: @ВикторБайкер can you please try **styep_id.val()** as i have pass in argument. **remove_estpgt_if_has_no_estpt($(this).attr("estpgt_id"),styep_id.val() );**

Comment: U have problem in `$("#styep_id_newval").(styep_id );`, there should be identifier.

Comment: @ВикторБайкер you are using first solution on second? Also i have uploaded second solution code